# Hive fetch one row at a time using select query

Tags: select, cursor, hive

I would like to fetch one row at a time using select query in hive. Something similar to cursors in SQL.But cursors are not supported in hive. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to use HBASE in such cases where you try to retrieve values one at a time as it enables really fast read and writes with scalability which enables near real time analytics.Whereas HIVE is mainly used for bulk data processing which is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `limit` at the end of the select query.

The following query fetch only one row from db.

`select * from TABLENAME limit 1;`

Comment: But wont it fetch the same row every time? I want some sort of query to fetch rows sequentially

Comment: No its not running in loop

Comment: try like this,set i=0 as a global variable; `select * from TABLENAME limit i,i++;`

Comment: Its not accepting i.. got error : mismatched input 'i' expecting Number near 'limit' in limit clause

Comment: Okay, FF101 is giving you fragments of the answer. You have to put the pieces together. The phrase suggested is not Hive, it's Java or Python code that you'd use to conduct a Hive query.

Although I don't like first answer (which is tantamount to, "don't know how to do that? Well don't do that."), it's actually true that Hive is ill suited for doing this. In a way, it's like sending a train to bring home one sack of groceries at a time.

Having said that, you can do what you propose. Using the LIMIT clause is only part of the puzzle though. You'll need to wrap it in other code.